# Counting the point which intercept in a line with opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-processing

I am working in vehicle counting with opencv and python programming, I already complete step:
1. Detect moving vehicle with BackgroundSubtractorMOG2
2. Draw rectangle on it, then poin a centroid of that
3. Draw a line (to indicate of the counting)

if that centroid accros/intercept with the line I want count that 1. but in my code sometime it add sometime no. Here the line code:

`cv2.line(frame,(0,170),(300,170),(200,200,0),2)`

and there the centroid:

```
if w > 20 and h > 25: 
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (180, 1, 0), 1)

    x1=w/2      
    y1=h/2
    cx=x+x1
    cy=y+y1
    centroid=(cx,cy)

    cv2.circle(frame,(int(cx),int(cy)),4,(0,255,0),-1)
```

my counting code:

```
 if cy==170:   
     counter=counter+1
```

Can anyone help me. please. for your advice thankyou!

Comment: Does the vehicle always travel in the same direction? If so then you can just alter your check to test for whether the vehicle has crossed the line. E.g. `if cy <= 170` for travelling up. Otherwise you'll need to determine the distance between the center and the line and check that instead of coordinates.

Comment: @ user3510227: thank you for your answer. Sorry, I already tried the code if cy <= 170 but it not accurate.

Comment: Which direction is the vehicle travelling? Can you upload a screenshot or drawing to help show the problem?

Comment: @ user3510227 : thank you for your help, sory if I dont upload the screenshoot, please open in  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-6VaPu2QKyKRjZISk9LS0NyQ3c/edit . Thank you for your help

Comment: I can't seem to access your upload, can you edit your answer and put it in there? Thanks

Comment: sorry, that error, use this. it works https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6VaPu2QKyKRjZISk9LS0NyQ3c/view?usp=sharing . Thank you

Comment: That makes things much clearer. I think you should try checking whether the line intersects a point on the rectangle rather than the centroid. I'm going to guess your problem is due to the small size of the centroid,the quick speed of the vehicles and the slow frame rate of the camera.

Comment: @ user3510227 : Thank you for your reply. I think so to make a rectangle to indicator of counting than a centroid, is the rectangle much effective than a centroid. I will try it, hey thank you for your idea. About the problem of slow rate camera yeah thats true I know that too, but I dont have any idea to solve that problem. Thank you for your helping idea.

Comment: With the slow camera, you could try storing the vehicle position and comparing it the its position in the next frame. If it was originally below the line and is now above it update the counter.

Comment: @ user3510227 : thank you for the reply. Ok, I will try that for experiment. But how about I use a normal speed camera?

Comment: A higher camera framerate should help with your current method of checking for intersections. But you might still encounter (rare) situations where a vehicle skips over the line between frames due to its speed / positioning and isn't counted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach that would work **independently** of the video frame rate. Assuming that you are able to track a car's *centroid* at each frame, I would save the last two centroids' position (`last_centroid` and `centroid` in my code) and process as follows:

1. compute the intercepting line equation's parameters ( (a,b,c) from [aX + bY + c = 0](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m445w04/notes/vector/equations.html))
2. compute the equation's parameters of the segment line between `last_centroid` and `centroid`
3. find if the two lines are intersecting
4. if so, increment your counter

Here is how I implemented it in OpenCV (Python):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import collections

Params = collections.namedtuple('Params', ['a','b','c']) #to store equation of a line

def calcParams(point1, point2): #line's equation Params computation
    if point2[1] - point1[1] == 0:
         a = 0
         b = -1.0
    elif point2[0] - point1[0] == 0:
        a = -1.0
        b = 0
    else:
        a = (point2[1] - point1[1]) / (point2[0] - point1[0])
        b = -1.0

    c = (-a * point1[0]) - b * point1[1]
    return Params(a,b,c)

def areLinesIntersecting(params1, params2, point1, point2):
    det = params1.a * params2.b - params2.a * params1.b
    if det == 0:
        return False #lines are parallel
    else:
        x = (params2.b * -params1.c - params1.b * -params2.c)/det
        y = (params1.a * -params2.c - params2.a * -params1.c)/det
        if x <= max(point1[0],point2[0]) and x >= min(point1[0],point2[0]) and y <= max(point1[1],point2[1]) and y >= min(point1[1],point2[1]):
            print("intersecting in:", x,y)
            cv2.circle(frame,(int(x),int(y)),4,(0,0,255), -1) #intersecting point
            return True #lines are intersecting inside the line segment
        else:
            return False #lines are intersecting but outside of the line segment

cv2.namedWindow('frame')
frame = np.zeros((240,320,3), np.uint8)

last_centroid = (200,200) #centroid of a car at t-1
centroid = (210,180) #centroid of a car at t

line_params = calcParams(last_centroid, centroid)
intercept_line_params = calcParams((0,170), (300,170))
print("Params:", line_params.a,line_params.b,line_params.c) 

while(1):
    cv2.circle(frame,last_centroid,4,(0,255,0), -1) #last_centroid
    cv2.circle(frame,centroid,4,(0,255,0), -1) #current centroid
    cv2.line(frame,last_centroid,centroid,(0,0,255),1) #segment line between car centroid at t-1 and t
    cv2.line(frame,(0,170),(300,170),(200,200,0),2) #intercepting line
    print("AreLinesIntersecting: ",areLinesIntersecting(intercept_line_params,line_params,last_centroid,centroid)) 
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(15) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here are some results:

[image: Fig1. Segment is intersecting the line]

*Fig1. Segment is intersecting the line* (intercepting line in **blue** - segment line between `last_centroid` and `centroid` in **red**)

[image: Fig2. Segment is NOT intersecting the line]

*Fig2. Segment is NOT intersecting the line*

**N.B.** I found the formulas to calculate the intersection point [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/geometry-concepts-line-intersection-and-its-applications/).

I hope my approach will help to address your problem.

Comment: First of all thanks for the great approach and wonderful explanation. So how to apply this approach for detecting centroids crossing tangential or inclined lines which are drawn by mouse click events.

Answer (score 0):

To assume that the centroid will assume a position 170 (in x or y) is wrong, because videos generally works at 30 fps, that mean you will get 30 centroid locations per second which means even if there the object crosses the line, it may never be 170!

To counter this, one method that can be used is defining a line margin. This means now you have a line margin x before actual line (y = 170) and x after the line margin.

So if your object falls anywhere in the margin, you can increment the counter. Now the next big part would be to make a tracking mechanism wherein you collect the list of point for each object and check if it fell in the margin.