# I'm trying to detect starbucks logo in a scene. How do I get rid of these artefacts in the bounding polylines?

Tags: python, opencv

I built a starbucks logo detector but I'm getting these weird artefacts when I draw the Polylines that are supposed to surround the logo.

Here is what a proper result looks like:

[image]

Here are some examples of the artefacts:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm using SIFT to detect the keypoints and draw the rectangle as taught in the OpenCV tutorials as [shown here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html):

```
 import numpy as np
 import cv2

 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
 img1 = cv2.imread('logo.png', 0)
 img1.resize(512, 512)
 kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
 while (True):
     ret, frame = cap.read()
     frame = findLogo(frame, kp1=kp1, des1=des1)
     cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
         break
 cap.release()
 out.release()
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()


 def findLogo(frame, kp1, des1):
     MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
     # Initiate SIFT detector
     sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

     img2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
     kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
     if len(kp2) != 0 and des2 is not None:
         FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
         index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
         search_params = dict(checks=50)

         flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

         matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

         # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
         good = []
         for m, n in matches:
             if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
                 good.append(m)
         if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
             src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
             dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

             M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)

             matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

             # h, w = img1.shape
             h = 512
             w = 512
             pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
             if M is not None:
                 dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
                 frame = cv2.polylines(frame, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0, 255, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

         else:
             print("Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
             matchesMask = None 
     return frame
```

I see that they occur when the program cannot detect the image. There are lines in the program to prevent this, (and it does work most of the time like when there is nothing on screen), but this error is still happening. Changing `MIN_MATCH_COUNT` to a higher number didn't help. As you can see here:

[image]

the artefact appears even when there are 37 good matches. Setting it too high means that the program wont find the logo unless the phone is perfectly still.

How can I get rid of those artefacts? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *deformed* contours are due to the **homography** not being properly computed.

Here is a way to discard *bad contours* when the object you're looking for has a **rectangular shape**:

- Find the *shortest* and *longest sides* of the contour and calculate the **relative gap** between both sides : *| longest - shortest | / longest*. If the *relative gap* is too big then it probably means the contour is bad.

---

Now, four methods that can work with **any contours** (not only rectangular contours):

- Set thresholds for the *contour's area* (that can be calculated using [`contourArea`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1)). The *contour's area* should neither be to small nor to large.
- Check the number of **inliers** given by the [`findHomography`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) function. If this number is bellow a certain threshold (for instance, 10), then discard the contour.
- Check that *any edge* of the contour doesn't **intersect** any *other edge*. If that's the case, then you can be sure the contour is bad.
- You can also try this [function](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2588/check-if-homography-is-good/) that reads the **homography** matrix **values** and returns true or false whether the homography is "*nice*" or not. (you might need to tweak the values inside the function for your needs).

---

Discarding all the bad contours is *not an easy task*, but by **using several** of the **methods** explained above, you should get rid of the majority of wrong contours.

Comment: Editing the question title to something harder to understand won't help others find this question if they have the same problem. And, if your understanding is indeed correct, then we don't need to attract more answers; only would-be askers.

Comment: Does this work for *any* four-sided shape? You could say [quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) instead of rectangle.

Comment: @jpaugh thanks for your comments. I thought the initial title ("_I'm trying to detect starbucks logo in a scene. How do I get rid of these artefacts in the bounding polylines?_") was to _vague_ to be found by other folks with similar problems. Indeed, the original title didn't make reference to the _OpenCV_ functions that are the root of the problem (`findHomography` and `perspectiveTransform`). That's what I tried to address in my title. As for the second remark, actually it does only work for rectangles. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  
I used the inliers counting (>15 from my testing) and the "Nice Homography" methods you mentioned above as they were the simplest to implement for me.   
It has worked pretty well so far. I dont see those artefacts anymore.  
I will test out the other methods as well because I'm curious.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to check if any lines are intersecting.  
I have 4 corner coordinates for the bounding rectangles. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Nissan Well, you would take the first and second corner, [calculate the equation's parameters of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252523/5799975) passing by these two points. Then check if this line intersects any of the 3 remaining segments and finally, repeat this process for every segment. However, I believe that the [`niceHomography`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2588/check-if-homography-is-good/) function already take care of this by checking if the transformation is orientation-preserving (see @RuiMarques answer bellow the linked question).